# How can i use tinymce with ajax with on a single click

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce

when use tinymce without ajax, it works fine on a single click. but when use with ajax it works only when a user double click on the button.

I want to use ajax jquery with tinymce on my comment page. please how can I stop it firing a double click before it can submit my form to the database